# How to set up all domains as "virtually hosted" with Postfix

Tags: postfix, alias

I have configured a Postfix server with the main domain and several virtual domains, cross-checking multiple tutorials and the [official documentation on virtual hosting](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html#virtual_alias). The Postfix is also set up to ultimately pass all mails to Dovecot, which should handle the (Unix) user mailboxes. In other words, all I need Postfix to do is address rewriting on the receiving end.

The (to my knowledge) important excerpts from my configuration are as follows (if anything important is missing, please remind me, I'll edit the question):

#### `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
myhostname = mail.first_domain.tld
mydomain = first_domain.tld

mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain, mail.$mydomain

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases

virtual_alias_domains = second_domain.tld, third_domain.tld, ...
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual

local_transport = dovecot
mailbox_transport = dovecot
virtual_transport = dovecot
```

#### `/etc/postfix/master.cf`:

```
# ...
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
    flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/libexec/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${recipient}
# ...
```

#### `/etc/postfix/virtual`:

```
postmaster@second_domain.tld        postmaster
postmaster@third_domain.tld         postmaster
# ...
```

#### `/etc/aliases`:

```
postmaster@first_domain.tld         postmaster
# ...
```

In my use case, I don't need to make any distinction between local and virtual mail delivery. I'd like to simply rewrite the addresses if an appropriate rule is found. If not, just pass the mail as-is. However, the virtual hosting documentation very clearly states to **"NEVER list a virtual alias domain name as a mydestination domain!"**

**Is there a way to use only virtual delivery for everything?** Completely forgo the `/etc/aliases` file for configuration simplicity. Ideally, I'd like to be able to just define all receiving addresses manually and don't mind explicitly writing them out.